Coherent PDF: Does it support variables, like PDFtk?
Does anybody know whether Coherent PDF support variables, like PDFtk?
This works:
cpdf -merge input1.pdf 1-3 input2.pdf input1.pdf 4-~1 -o output.pdf

But this doesn't:
cpdf -merge A=input1.pdf B=input2.pdf A1-3 B A4-~1 -o output.pdf


All commands should be at https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf

@ChanganAuto Thanks for the link, but no need to downvote, because I looked into the manual before asking. The manual does use this syntax, but only once, and for a different case: cpdf -load-ttf A=NotoSans-Black.ttf -font A -add-text "-%Page-" -o out.pdf. That is, after looking into the manual, it is not neverthelss really clear to me whether variables should or should not work what I'm trying to use them for.

Cpdf does not use variables. However if you mention a file twice, like in your first example, the file will only be read once, and the merge command will know that the two parts of it are from the same file. There should therefore be no bloating of the output or loss of speed. If there is either, that's a bug and you can report it on Github.

@johnwhitington Well, thanks.
